# Java-static arrays

Tags: java

i have a class called (User) and i want to make a multidimensional array of it
i have wrote

```
static User [][] userlist=new User[6][];
```

and i have a compiler error that is :
illegal start of expression

thanks a lot .

Comment: Please use correct capitalization when posting questions.

Comment: You click the outlined checkbox next to the answer that you think is correct.

Comment: @Ruba: Regarding the compile error you're getting:  I'm guessing you're trying to put that declaration *inside a method*.  The static keyword only applies to member variables to indicate that they are shared by all instances of the class, and not just the class itself.  As such, it must be outside of any method.  If that's not the problem you're having you'll need to post more context.

Comment: yes that's right ,the declaration is inside a method.thank you .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's an example of a 5x5 2-dimensional array:

```
private static int[][] matrix = new int[5][5];

//set index 1, 2 to 5
matrix[1][2] = 5;
```

The static part really makes no difference; just declare the member as static.

Comment: Oops, thanks for the typo fix.

Comment: I have tried to do that ... but it didn't work...

Comment: @Ruba: can you give more details than "it didn't work"?  (Good to see you've found the accept answer button; though it may be premature for this question :-).  Take a look at your past questions and consider accepting answers for them: http://stackoverflow.com/users/367018/ruba)

Comment: i have User class... and i want to make a multidimensional array of this class. so i have wrote :  static User [][] userlist=new User[6][]; and i have a compiler error

Comment: And what's the compile error?  (You may want to edit this into your question if it's too difficult to show in a comment).

Answer (score 9):

Similar to @Mark solution, you can initialise a multi-dimensional array

```
private static int[][] matrix = {
    { 1,2,3,4,5 },
    { 6,7,8,9,10 }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static int[][] arr = new int[2][4] ;
arr[0][0]=1;
arr[0][1]=2;
.
.
arr[0][3]=4;
```

Comment: I don't think that counts as `multi` dimensional

Comment: @Woot4Moo , Ooops :) updated the code

Comment: There ya go, I removed my downvote accordingly

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of nice answers, so this is more informative than anything:

The problem is that all dimensions *must* be specified explicitly or implicitly -- and the `new X[..][..][..]` etc, (explicitly specified dimensions) form requires that each dimension (`..`) is a (non-negative) integer expression. The javac compiler is throwing that error because it found the last `]` but was expecting an integer expression.

```
new User[6][/*you need an integer expression here*/];
```

Happy coding.